# Bazelisk builds hello_world example successfully but doesn't print the output

Tags: c++, bazel, mediapipe

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have the latest Version (v1.16.0) of Bazelisk installed.
I wanted to use it for building with MediaPipe and tryed to build and run their C++ hello_world example just like they described [here](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/hello_world_cpp).

However after building successfully with no error it doesn't print out the 10 rows of Hello World's. I've tried to run it with:
`bazelisk run --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world`

The following output is printed:

`WARNING: /home/anwender/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/BUILD:54:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use. WARNING: /home/anwender/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/tool/BUILD:197:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use. INFO: Analyzed target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured). INFO: Found 1 target... Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world up-to-date: bazel-bin/mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world/hello_world INFO: Elapsed time: 0.323s, Critical Path: 0.00s INFO: 1 process: 1 internal. INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total actionINFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world/hello_world`

There are no Hello World's printed after this, which would have been expected.

I've also tried to only build it but i can't find the output file. The build is succesfull but no info is printed about the location of the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing the line before the Bazel invocation in the linked documentation:

```
$ export GLOG_logtostderr=1
```

Comment: Thanks! I've typed that line but i must have gotten a typo in it somewhere.